# What does PerspectiveCamera's translate change in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I am using the PerspectiveCamera in three.js. I want to move the camera forward and backward, so I try to use translates and it works well.

I also need to get the camera's position. But the translateZ doesn't change the position of the camera. So what does translateZ change?

Comment: Did you log the position before and after translateZ to verify it doesn't change?

Answer (score 0):

All Three.js objects have a [`translateX, translateY, translateZ`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.translateX) method, which changes the position along the axis by the given units. translateZ() moves it along the Z-axis. If you're not seeing any change in the camera, try using larger values, maybe you're just not noticing it because moving forward/backward is a little less obvious than moving up/down or left/right.